# ViewModel support in Portable Class Library

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, portable-class-library

I am trying out the PCL in a VS 2010 project in which I would like to support WPF (4 and higher) and Silverlight (4 and higher). The [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  excerpt below is confusing to me.

It *seems* to be saying to reference System.Windows in the PCL project, but I don't see how to do that.

What must I do to have ICommand and INotifyPropertyChanged in my PCL project?

> Supporting the View Model Pattern     When you target Silverlight and
>   Windows Phone 7, you can implement the view model pattern in your
>   solution. The classes to implement this pattern are located in the
>   System.Windows.dll assembly from Silverlight. The System.Windows.dll
>   assembly is not supported when you create a Portable Class Library
>   project that targets the .NET Framework 4 or Xbox 360.
>
> The classes in this assembly include the following:
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection
>
> System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler
>
> System.Windows.Input.ICommand
>
> The .NET Framework 4 also contains these classes, but they are
>   implemented in 
>       assemblies other than System.Windows.dll. To use these classes with a Portable Class 
>       Library project, you must reference System.Windows.dll and not the assemblies listed in 
>       the .NET Framework 4 documentation

## EDIT

INotifyPropertyChanged is NOT available; the code below will not compile

```
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    ...

}
```

Comment: You tagged you code `pcl` for `Printer control language`. Did you mean `Portable Class Library` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the MSDN is confusing on this point (is there an error ?)

Basically, you have nothing to do !

Whe you create your PCL project, simply select appropriate frameworks.
[image: new pcl project]

PCL automatically manage references for you.

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Let's try !

Comment: That is the confusing part - I did that! See my edit; I am not getting access to INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Are you on VS 2010 with PCL add-in (like me) or VS2012 with nativee support?

Comment: VS 2010 with PCL (like you)

Comment: Oh I see what is going on - the project builds and you are correct. It's Resharper 6.x that isn't with the program, and highlighting what it can't resolve as errors!!. Cheers..

Comment: In VS 2012 the support expanded to ICommand as well. Reuires targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or higher, Silverlight 5 and higher, Windows Phone 8 and higher, and .NET for Windows Store.